# Android Item click listener in ListView

Tags: java, android

Hello I have custom adopter for a `ListView` how can I add `clickListener` on item and I also need a menu in item with some other button(DropDwons) I am new to android development I tried many solutions from internet but not working for me.

please help me

**My Code**

```
public class TrackAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Result> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Result> trackList = new ArrayList<>();

    public TrackAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Result> list) {
        super(context, 0 , list);
        mContext = context;
        trackList = list;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if(listItem == null)
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.track,parent,false);

        Result currentTrack = trackList.get(position);




        return listItem;
    }
}
```

**Item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_poster"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_album"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_release"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:text="Artist Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView_poster"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_name" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Add your `track.xml` file

Comment: @Dinesh Shingadiya added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give `id` to your `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` like:

```
android:id="@+id/parent"
```

And then create like

```
ConstraintLayout parent = (ConstraintLayout)listItem.findViewById(R.id.parent);
parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Code stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: but how will i get position of clicked  item  ?

Comment: Sorry i don't know which field in your `currentTrack` model, but if you use something like `currentTrack.getName()`, then use in `parent.setOnClickListener` you can get particular item with it's detail